# tinymce plugin to upload images

Tags: php, tinymce

I am using the plugin for tinymce to upload images *(justboil.com)*

i am uploading the images on

```
sub.domain.com/upload.php
```

and the upload folder is located at

```
domain.com/file_dump/tinymce_file_upload
```

i have put this in my config

```
$config['img_path'] = '/file_dump/tinymce_file_upload'; // Relative to domain name
$config['upload_path'] = substr($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],0,-3) . $config['img_path']; // Physical path. [Usually works fine like this]
```

it gets the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and removes 3 characters (for the subdomain) as the sub folder for the sub domain is located in the `public_html` folder

i am getting an error saying the upload path is invalid when i try to upload images

Comment: can you echo out `substr($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],0,-3)` ? what does that equal?

Comment: it shows home/username/public_html where as $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] would be home/username/public_html/sub

Comment: you need a `/` on the front of that

Answer (score 0):

your upload path looks with  '//'
domain.com`//`file_dump/tinymce_file_upload

so Just remove '/' from $config['img_path']

$config['img_path'] = 'file_dump/tinymce_file_upload';